# ASP.NET Core jQuery POST - Incorrect Content-Type despite correctly formatted headers

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have researched similar threads, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48672104/invalidoperationexception-incorrect-content-type-asp-net-core) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69636204/net-core-5-post-response-returns-incorrect-content-type-application-json), and have determined that this deserves its own thread, as I could not find any help in an hour of research.

I am trying to send a POST request to an ASP.NET Core host from a jQuery request. This is how I've formatted my POST request in the frontend:

```
            $.ajax({
            url: "/Merge",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            datatype: "json",
            data: {
                "example": "examplecontent"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
```

This is the way I'm ingesting it in the backend for testing purposes:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var x = HttpContext.Request.Form;
        Dictionary<string, string> exampleDict = new();
        //exampleDict.Add("Testing", HeaderElem);
        JsonResult result = new(exampleDict);
        return result;
    }
```

Despite including complete headers, I have been getting this error on the backend claiming that I have an 'incorrect content type':

[image]

What might be wrong with my request?

Comment: As an aside to the actual issue - why are you using `HttpContent.Request.Form` in the first instance? MVC is designed to be used with Models in the request - it's why we have the ModelBinder to bind request parameters to concrete objects. Why not use that instead?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've spent a day and a half following recipes online using MVC standards to no avail. I have Models built, but I'm choosing not to use them until I can figure out what is wrong with my Post request. Once I get this resolved, I'll go back to using models.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce using a brand new ASP.NET Core MVC project (targetting .NET 5) and it worked just fine. Is your controller (I assume `MergeController`) inheriting from `Controller`? e.g. `public class MergeController : Controller`

Comment: @EthanHill in that case this issue sounds like you've made an error in your configuration somewhere as the code will work with the default config.

Comment: You are posting to "/Merge" in your ajax request. But the controller action you show us is for Index. Are you doing some kind of redirection between ajax and the action you are debugging?

Comment: No redirection. ASP.NET seems to automatically route traffic from localhost/Merge to the default (Index) function because of the name of the class (MergeController). I'm not sure why it works, but it seems to at least route correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to fix the action

```
[Route("~/Merge")]
public IActionResult Index(string example)
{
       return Ok ( new { example = example } );
}
```

Comment: I've checked this out, and while this works in Insomnia, the same error appears as above. I'm going to investigate my configuration to see if something else is wrong.